# How to display my bot commands like that?

Tags: python, discord.py

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1KxN.png)

I have some issues with the last api update (all my commands doesn't wanted to work),
i figured out a method but this seems to not work  too :  `add_command(command, /)`.
There is my code :

```
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="test", url="My url"))


@commands.command()
async def shutown(ctx):
    print("tests")
    await ctx.send("good bye ")
    await ctx.bot.logout()

bot.add_command(shutdown)
```

Comment: The commands in question are "slash commands" or discord.py calls them `app_commands`. Here's an example of how to set those up: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you dont have to manually keep adding back the command, instead it can be automatic.

```
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="test", url="My url"))

@bot.command()
async def shutown(ctx):
    print("tests")
    await ctx.send("good bye ")
    await ctx.bot.logout()
```

Try to change your code to this, and see if it works.
All that got changed is the decorator for the command. Instead of `@commands.command()`, I used `@bot.command()`

Unless you done this before, can you tell me if you have "intents"
If not, then in the bot variable, you need to add an argument "intents" and give it the value of discord.Intents.default() or discord.Intents.all()

If you haven't the bot variable should contain this:

```
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(
    command_prefix = "/", 
    intents = discord.Intents.default() # Or discord.Intents.all()
)
```